# Почему происходит повторная инициализация бинов?

Tags: java, spring, config

Spring MVC + Angular. Конфигурация в аннотациях, частично в web.xml. Использую Tomcat 7. При запуске все отлично, но как только приложение загружается, идет повторное заполнение mysql и повторная инициализация бинов. Мой web.xml такой:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- @Configuration classes or package -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.springapp.mvc.config.web.WebConfig</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/staticPages/home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Лог:

```
Connected to server
[2015-06-30 02:59:50,269] Artifact NLBB2:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
июн 30, 2015 2:59:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\roman\Roman\ProjectsIdeaMercurial\target\NLBB2\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
июн 30, 2015 2:59:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
июн 30, 2015 2:59:52 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
июн 30, 2015 2:59:52 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 30 14:59:52 GMT+05:00 2015]; root of context hierarchy
июн 30, 2015 2:59:52 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Successfully resolved class for [com.springapp.mvc.config.web.WebConfig]
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
июн 30, 2015 2:59:53 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists salaries
Hibernate: create table salaries (ID integer not null auto_increment, PLAYER_NAME varchar(255), POSITION varchar(255), SALARY integer, TEAM_NAME varchar(255), primary key (ID))
июн 30, 2015 2:59:54 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
File Found
июн 30, 2015 2:59:54 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@5828da3d] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Hibernate: insert into salaries (PLAYER_NAME, POSITION, SALARY, TEAM_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into salaries (PLAYER_NAME, POSITION, SALARY, TEAM_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Good time to load DB
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/salaries],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary> com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.getSalaries()
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/addSalary],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.addSalary(com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary)
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/deleteSalary],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Integer com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.deleteBook(java.lang.Integer)
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/salaryId],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.editSalary(java.lang.Integer)
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/editSalary],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.editSalary(com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary)
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/staticPages/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 30 14:59:52 GMT+05:00 2015]; root of context hierarchy
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3538 ms
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcherServlet': initialization started
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringDispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Tue Jun 30 14:59:55 GMT+05:00 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
июн 30, 2015 2:59:55 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 33 ms
[2015-06-30 02:59:55,796] Artifact NLBB2:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-06-30 02:59:55,796] Artifact NLBB2:war exploded: Deploy took 5 527 milliseconds
Hibernate: select salary0_.ID as ID1_0_, salary0_.PLAYER_NAME as PLAYER_N2_0_, salary0_.POSITION as POSITION3_0_, salary0_.SALARY as SALARY4_0_, salary0_.TEAM_NAME as TEAM_NAM5_0_ from salaries salary0_
июн 30, 2015 3:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\webapps\NLBB2.war
июн 30, 2015 3:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\webapps\NLBB2\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jun 30 15:00:01 GMT+05:00 2015]; root of context hierarchy
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-contex.xml]
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFO: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.5.RELEASE
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.5.RELEASE
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser parse
INFO: Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false.
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFO: Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll' for /**
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthenticationConfigBuilder createLoginPageFilterIfNeeded
INFO: No login page configured. The default internal one will be used. Use the 'login-page' attribute to set the URL of the login page.
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.6
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
июн 30, 2015 3:00:01 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from url: file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/NLBB2/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: Configured SessionFactory: null
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary on table salaries
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory newConnectionProvider
INFO: Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.5.25
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC driver: MySQL Connector Java, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.34 ( Revision: jess.balint@oracle.com-20141014163213-wqbwpf1ok2kvo1om )
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch size: 15
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query cache: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createCacheProvider
INFO: Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Echoing all SQL to stdout
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Statistics: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
INFO: building session factory
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: Running hbm2ddl schema export
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: exporting generated schema to database
июн 30, 2015 3:00:02 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: schema export complete
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFO: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7b677c4c, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@4711a0df, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5658b4ec, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@59ce1e3d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6b2364da, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@60b25b29, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5d7f1257, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@418d3db5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@1fce57b2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@23df776e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2419e928, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@211a539c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@476737be]
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
INFO: Checking whether login URL '/spring_security_login' is accessible with your configuration
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@35069006] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2465 ms
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jun 30 15:00:03 GMT+05:00 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.5.RELEASE
июн 30, 2015 3:00:03 PM org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser parse
INFO: Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false.
File Found
Hibernate: insert into salaries (PLAYER_NAME, POSITION, SALARY, TEAM_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into salaries (PLAYER_NAME, POSITION, SALARY, TEAM_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Good time to load DB
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/sortColum/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.sort(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.getSalaries(org.springframework.ui.Model)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/addSalary],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.addSalary(com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/addSalary],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.addSalary(org.springframework.ui.Model)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/deleteSalary/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.deleteBook(java.lang.Integer)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/editSalary/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.editSalary(org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.Integer)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/editSalary],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.springapp.mvc.controller.SalaryController.editSalary(com.springapp.mvc.domain.Salary,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jun 30 15:00:03 GMT+05:00 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jun 30 15:00:03 GMT+05:00 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
июн 30, 2015 3:00:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 1224 ms
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по логу, у вас два веб-приложения. Одно где-то в `C:\Users\roman\Roman\ProjectsIdeaMercurial\target\NLBB2\`, а второе установлено в томкате: `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\webapps\NLBB2.war`. Вот они оба и загружаются.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, видно когда то руки засунул туда, не подумав к чему приведет!